# Reset an app after click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am developing a game using Apache Cordova. It has 4 levels and a menu which contains options like play game etc. When I clear level 3, and go to menu to play the game once again, the variables are not reset and the game jumps to level 4 after clearing level 2. Level 2 is also not cleared fully. How can I reset the application after I click Play Game. When I quit the application and start it once again, the game works perfectly for the first time. To play the game once again without any problem, I have to restart the application once again.I want the application to start as it starts for the first time without exiting it. How can I do that? Please tell all the steps as I am new to Javascript and Cordova.

Comment: While resetting app clear your all variables and localStorage may be that will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.reload();` to reload the Cordova WebView. This will reset any JS variable values held in memory.

If you are using local storage to persist data between sessions, you can invoke `localStorage.clear();` (before the above) to clear any persisted values.